# Script to download csv file with data after running search query using Python 3 not working

Tags: python-3.x, download

Trying to download a CSV file after running a search query.  On the website listed in the code below, you have to click Download CSV after the search results are back to download file. Script attached below.  Appreciate help modifying it so it downloads a file with relevant content.

```
import requests, csv, urllib
from urllib import request    

URL = 'http://families.naeyc.org/programs/csv/CSV?attach=list'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
with open('file.csv','wb') as fx:
    fx.write(response)
```